how to export datasource from looker to azure adls gen 2 storage cloud
is any way to migrate the data from looker to azure adls gen 2 cloud storage.
I can see only export the data to google drive / email options to export the data. kindly let me know is any way to integrate the looker data to azure cloud storage
